# MPI summation of double precision numbers

Tags: floating-point, sum, fortran, mpi

I am trying to implement Neumaier algorithm to sum double precision numbers over an array of elements gathered by MPI call. This is needed because the values we are summing are drag coefficient values, usually compared by the 10^-5 decimal position. Comparing the results with the ones obtained with the serial version of the code, the values are still very different, like if the algorithm had some kind of problem. Am I doing something wrong in the procedure below ?

```
!
! ----------------------------------------------------------------------
!
!     SUBROUTINE mpisum
!
!     
      subroutine dmpisum(num,total,nproc)
      USE shared_data
      implicit none
!
      integer(kind=4) :: ierr,nproc,i
      real(kind=8) :: num,total,c,t
      real(kind=8), dimension(nproc) :: num_r
!
      total    = 0.0d0
      num_r(:) = 0.0d0
!
!     Now, gather all the values from all procs.
!
      call MPI_GATHER(num,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,num_r,1, & 
                            MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
!
!     Now, perform the Neumaier algorithm to sum all values avoiding rounding
!     errors.
!
      if (myid.eq.0) then
         total = num_r(1)
         c     = 0.0d0
         t     = 0.0d0
!
         do i = 2, nproc
            t = total + num_r(i)
            if (dabs(total) >= dabs(num_r(i))) then
                c = c + ( (total-t) + num_r(i) )
            else
                c = c + ( (num_r(i) - t) + total)
            end if
            total = t
         end do
!
         total = total + c
!
      end if
!
      end subroutine dmpisum
```

The dmpisum is being called in all procs (no if I am master rank....).

Comment: Please show us your results and explain which results you expect instead. See [ask] and [mcve] for more. We need more details to understand your problem properly or more easily. Tell us how much are they different and which numbers are they.

Comment: It is likely *not* the problem here, but note that kind=8 means something different than DOUBLE PRECISION. In many compilers they are the same, but not in all of them. Kind numbers like 4 and 8 are not portable.